# RHEL Mail From Address

Tags: email, rhel5

I have several virtual servers that were cloned from the same original server.  Whenever I send mail from them using "mail", the from address shows up as the name from the original server but the email address in angle brackets is correct.

The email listing shows this For example:

Application Owner server01 <appowner@server2.xyz.com>

The server01 is the name of the original virtual server that this was cloned from.  Where do I change this?   Note that nothing is being set in the "mail" command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  The name was being pulled from the /etc/passwd file.  Changing it there changed it when sendmail was used.